# Design question - Configuring connection pool for different types of outbound calls from an application

Tags: connection-pooling, reactor-netty

I have an application that makes outbound calls using following mechanisms.

- HTTP
- HTTPS
- HTTPS with mSSL

Should I have one connection pool for all applications or should I be using different connection pool per client/outbound connection because the SSL context is configured on the connection pool with the certificates?

If I have one connection pool wouldn't the HTTP call also be made with the SSL context configured on the connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

Reactor Netty will create 3 different connection pools in the case above. It is not possible to use a connection pool with TLS for calls that are HTTP. The selection of the connection pool that will be used is based on the remote address + the configuration for the client.

Comment: Makes sense but it is HttpClient which is preconfigured with SSL context (maybe I didnt phrase it properly in my original question). How does it determine when to use SSL factory? Is the recommendation to use different HTTP client (one with SSL context and one without), same connection pool or different connection pool etc.,

`if (sslContext != null) {
    httpClient = httpClient.secure(sslProvider -> sslProvider.sslContext(sslContext));
}`

Comment: May be it is better to move the discussion to Gitter chat (https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor-netty) so that you can explain your use case.